# Possible to print 4 columns?

Tags: java, nested-loops

I want to know if its possible to print 4 columns in the output with numbers in it.

I know we can print with many columns but I am not sure with nested for loops

For example here's what I've done so far.

```
for(int x = 1; x <=5; x++)
  {
     for(int y = 1; y<5; y++)
     {
        int area = (x*y);           
        int perimeter = (2*x + 2*y);
```

but now I'm stuck on how to print them in four columns each by side.

EXAMPLE:

[Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nWG9.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Are you asking how to put the values you got from nested loop into columns?

Comment: Use ``System.out.print`` to output stuff in the same line...

Comment: @VirtuosoMessi Yes but with a header and the numbers from the loop

Comment: You can use System.out.printf() to better format the columns

Comment: Please provide an example of what kind of output you want

Answer (score 1):

This will let you print out the numbers in 4 separate columns.

Using `System.out.printf()` allows you to format the spacing given to each number. In the code below it allocates 4 spaces to each `x` and `y` then 5 spaces to `area` and `perimeter`.

```
System.out.print("  X   Y Area Perimeter\n"); // Column headers

for(int x = 1; x <=5; x++) {

     for(int y = 1; y<5; y++) {

        int area = (x*y);           
        int perimeter = (2*x + 2*y);

        // Prints the numbers out with formatted spacing
        System.out.printf("%4d%4d%5d%5d\n", x, y, area, perimeter);
     }
}
```

You can adjust the spacing to your liking. I just put those numbers so it would line up better with the headers.

Comment: Using `\n` makes the output platform-specific. Better to use `println` and `printf(...%n...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just print them, use any column separator that you like.

```
System.out.println(x + "," + y + "," + area + "," + perimeter);
```